# Merge tags [hibernate-validator] and [hibernate-validation]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

`hibernate-validator` refers to the JSR 303 implementation and [all 7 `hibernate-validation` questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hibernate-validation?sort=newest) refer to the combination of `hibernate` and `validation` (which is a much better approach than a separate tag) and `hibernate-validator`.